# What kind of soft questions are acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I have come to understand that this site is mostly used by researching mathematicians. I'm a math undergrad, but I have a few questions I'd like to ask researching mathematicians regarding approaching higher mathematics. Would such questions be acceptable?

Comment: I think you should rather try math.stackexchange.com. -- While on this site occasionally soft questions are welcomed, it is probably not advisable for a new user to start with a soft question, or even to ask several such questions in quick succession.

Comment: Generally no.  But you should have listed your questions here because you're potentially being too non-specific for us to give productive answers.  I second Stefan Kohl's comment.

Comment: The kind with hard answers (sic)!

Comment: Tommy, what are your questions?

Answer (score 12):

Mainly: keep in mind that MathOverflow is a "question and answer" forum.  Not a "discussion" forum.  Not an "opinion" forum.